# How to address inconsistency between Title, body and tags?

Tags: discussion, support

Does “Unclear what you are asking” already cover inconsistencies between Title, body and tags that introduce some uncertainty but where the OP’s intent can be deduced with reasonable probability (though will be a wrong guess quite often) or should there be another close reason that addresses this specifically?

Examples seem to include [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) where perhaps the question posting process is suggesting these tags automatically and new users don’t know better than to override the suggestion. I think there may be other examples also.

An alternative, undoubtedly with other consequences however, might be to cease from making such suggestions (if they are being made) – or make it more obvious they are automated and that the Usage guidance should be read before a choice is made.

In the case of [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet), and apart from my understanding that many [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) questions posted on SO really belong on Web Applications, some answers may apply to both anyway. Sometimes the OP does not mind whether an answer applies to one or the other only, sometimes OP does seek a single solution that works for both, and sometimes coverage of both is sought but one for each would be acceptable.

A solution that works for both (if available) may not be optimal for one of the two, or possibly even either.

An example (the link is to an SQL solution):

[image: metaSO305555 example]

Comment: I never take tags into account when trying to understand a question, it's just a useful mechanism for finding questions I might be able to help with. In situations like above, I think it would make more sense to suggest alternative tags to help get the question more visibility rather than trying to close it.

Comment: Flagging to close the article because of poor tagging is not a constructive idea, especially as the question and its answers may be very helpful. Perhaps an option to flag as ambiguous tags, which lead to a new review task for others to comment on?

Comment: The body of the question is the most important for understanding what the question actually is. If either the title or the tags are misleading, submitting an edit for the title or proposing new tags is by far the simplest and most efficient way to deal with it. I still disagree with the possibility of another close action from this.

Comment: In that case, just answer the question without the context of the application, if it makes sense to do so. If the title and question proposed is generic enough to be considered ambiguous without specific tags, then I would argue that is a good enough reason to raise an ambiguous flag.

Comment: If the question is answerable without the context of the tags (i.e. "How do I sort a list efficiently?"), a generic answer to the problem should be given and tags ignored. If the problem needs the context of the application, and it is not present in the question, then it should be flagged. I do not agree with tags adding context to a question, it should be clear without them.

Comment: Should be closed because it is unclear what is being asked. Alternatively ask the OP to clarify the question further in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

To summarise my comments:

I feel tags should not add context to a question, that is the purpose of the title and body. If a question is too ambiguous without tags, then the question should be closed because it is unclear what is being asked. Alternatively, you could ask the original poster to clarify the question further in a comment.

Comment: I feel language tags DO add context. There's no need to mention jQuery in the title or question if the question is tagged jQuery, for example.

Comment: I disagree for the simple reason that tags are tiny and at the bottom of the question. I don't see them until after I've tried to understand the question and problem. If tags are to provide context to a question, then they should be much more visible and presented first along with the title.

Comment: @Tro Maybe you should adjust your workflow to read the tags before trying to make sense of a question instead of blaming them of being somewhere where you don't see them. It's not like you don't know that there are tags.

Comment: @FUZxxl As I've already mentioned, if I should consider tags as part of the context in a question then they need to be moved to the top of the question, perhaps alongside the title, so I can have that information at the very beginning. Until that happens, the average user is not going to take them into account from the start, and so the average user will not consider tags as part of the context of a question.